# Script to monitor Internet connection stability

Tags: scripts, internet, router, monitoring

I would like it to be reported every time that the my router loses its internet connection.

I would like to have my Ubuntu system send me an email every time that the router's system log displays the message "ethernet link down".

Is that possible? I believe that I would have to write a script, am I right?

Comment: How do you access the router's log? Via a browser? More importantly, how will the mail be sent if your internet connection is lost? O.o

Comment: It would be sent after the connection is restored, since what I'm trying to have on record is the internet connection instability. Anyway, I believe that our friend just posted a script that does the job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like that in a cron job

```
#!/bin/bash
dt=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "$dt:Online"
else
    echo "$dt:Offline"
    mail -s "Internet connection lost on $(hostname) at $(date)" 
fi
```

I personnaly have a script that stores reports of connection quality (depending on package speedtest you can get from `apt-get install speedtest-cli`

```
#!/bin/bash
#***************************************
# FOR CRONTAB
# */10 * * * * /location/of/my-internet-test.sh
#***************************************
LOG_FILE="/var/log/internet_test_$(hostname).csv"
mkdir -p $(dirname $LOG_FILE)
DT=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
SPEED_TEST_RES=$(speedtest-cli --simple 2>/dev/null)
#set -o xtrace
DL=$(echo $SPEED_TEST_RES | awk '{print $5}')
UL=$(echo $SPEED_TEST_RES | awk '{print $8}')
PING=$(echo $SPEED_TEST_RES | awk '{print $2}')
#set -x
#echo "Ping: '$PING' DL:'${DL}' UL:'${UL}'"
[[ -z "$DL" ]] && { DL=0; UL=0; PING=0; }
echo "$DT,$PING,$DL,$UL" >> $LOG_FILE
```

Note that its a [better practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119069/cron-vs-sleep-which-is-the-better-one-in-terms-of-efficient-cpu-memory-utiliz) to call a script regularly from a cron than doing a loop

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I will try this script. I also did some research and came up with this one: 

`#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    wget -q --tries=5 --timeout=20 -O - http://www.google.com > /dev/null
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then :
        
    else
        echo $(date) "offline" | tee -a /place_to_save_log/offline.csv
    fi
    sleep 5
done`

It doesn't send me an email, but it creates a local log, wich is also very helpful.

Comment: @Eduardo I'll put your log file in /var/log/yourLogFile.log and will finish it with .log extension! csv is coma separated values, if you want to do a statistic you'd better in fact do a csv log file with date & time (see date command) and then you could do a graph with `gnuplot`

Comment: `ping -c1 google.com` is simpler than wget.

Answer (score 11):

I appreciate this is an old question, but I found it searching for a solution, so I ended up writing one. It's a shell script that checks for internet connectivity, and logs any outages, along with the re-connected link speed. Feel free to grab it:

https://github.com/TristanBrotherton/netcheck

Comment: Good job, good job!

Comment: Well done, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since the introduction of the `ip` command you can do something with the `ip monitor` command. Try doing something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
ip -ts monitor neigh | while read event; do
    case "$event" in
      *router*FAILED*) POST_NOTIFICATION_OF_ROUTER_DOWN ;;
esac
done
```

The`ip monitor neigh` will monitor the states of the neighboring hosts. The router is a neigbor as well as a router.

When the router goes down the monitor sends a message like this:

```
[2020-04-19T07:22:59.322335] fe80::1256:3456:ffff:1212 dev ethusb1  router FAILED
```

When the router is up the message is like this:

```
[2020-04-19T07:30:15.291261]fe80::1256:3456:ffff:1212  dev ethusb1 lladdr 10:56:11:7e:42:49 router REACHABLE
```

The `shopt -s extglob` enables advanced bash parsing.

The `-ts` is for short timestamp format. It isn't functionally necessary for this, but I find it useful when logging the output.

To monitor all ip objects, try `ip -ts monitor all`.

Answer (score 0):

Because a comment containing a code snippet was hard to feed back into a file as valid syntax, I'm posting it as an answer here. It was basically what I was looking for, finding the amount of times the internet connection went down.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    wget -q --tries=5 --timeout=20 -O - http://www.google.com > /dev/null

    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then :
        else echo $(date) "offline" | tee -a $HOME/offline.csv
    fi

    sleep 5
done
```

Another great answer, found https://stackoverflow.com/a/14939373/7546562, shows this script. I've modified it to suit your needs, but be aware that it may not work on all OS distributions.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    # Test for network conection
    for interface in $(ls /sys/class/net/ | grep -v lo)
    do if [[ $(cat /sys/class/net/$interface/carrier) = 1 ]]; then OnLine=1; fi; done
    if ! [ $OnLine ]; then echo $(date) "offline" | tee -a $HOME/offline.csv; fi

    sleep 10
done
```

Finally, if you want, you can add the following by doing `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

```
su - YOUR_USER -c "bash /home/pi/Scripts/net2.sh" &
su - YOUR_USER -c "bash /home/pi/Scripts/net3.sh" &
```

Comment: `cat: /sys/class/net/virbr0-nic/carrier: Invalid argument` some carrier will return -EINVAL ... think you can use `$(</sys/class/net/$interface/carrier)` instead of `cat`. [Reading from sysfs returns EINVAL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/190967/380915)